# Extend complete ZfcUser Module

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I want to extend the ZfcUser module, but i do not want to edit the original ZfcUser files.
How can i extend files like the module.php, the view and form files?
or is it even possible to extend the complete module?

Answer (score 2):

For what reason do you need to extend the `ZfcUser\Module` class? In most cases, you have the ability to do it in a custom user module class, say `MyUser\Module`.

For other features, check out my answer to the question [ZF2, what's the best practice for working with Vendor Module's Form classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783873/zf2-whats-the-best-practice-for-working-with-vendor-modules-form-classes/9802230#9802230) and the [blogpst](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/117/use-3rd-party-modules-in-zend-framework-2) I created based on that afterwards. The question on SO uses still the old mechanism of `Zend\Di` but my blog post is updated to use the `Zend\ServiceManager` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the Tutorial. The Form is shown, but when i submit the form the values of the new fields are not submitted. I am using ZfcUser with ZfCUserDoctrine. I get an SQLError that the fields can not be null.

Comment: Check what values are populated in the form. You might have made a mistake in the filter. If in the filter the values aren't defined, you can't get them through to the entity.

Comment: For Every attribute i use this simple filter: `$filter->add(array('name' => 'zipCode',
'required' => true));` Do i need to extend a special function where the data is processed?