# Future Proofing Changes to Validation of Username/Password Field in ZFCUser

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I've been looking around at how to change the actual validation process of the registration fields in the ZFCUser module in Zend Framework 2.

There is a lot about extending and adding new fields etc. to the form but not validating these fields or extending the existing validation.

I have taken a look inside the code and found the RegistrationForm.php file and added my customer Regular Expression filters.

This works well and as expected but I am worried about this being over-written on any future upgrade.

How would I go about doing this so it is upgrade safe? Is it a case of extending a specific class or adding it as a local file in my custom modules as I have done with the view files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783873/zf2-whats-the-best-practice-for-working-with-vendor-modules-form-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've same problem as you, and also do not find proper solution. But IMHO better way than change original source code is to override one of the ZfcUser services.

There is a service called 'zfcuser_change_password_form' defined in zfc-user Module.php. If you create own service with same name - the original one will be overriden. So, first you need to define your own filter / validator class (YourFilter), then in your Module.php add:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        // ...
        'factories' => array(
            // ... 
            'zfcuser_change_password_form' => function ($sm) {
                $options = $sm->get('zfcuser_module_options');
                $form = new \ZfcUser\Form\ChangePassword(
                       null, $sm->get('zfcuser_module_options')
                    );
                $form->setInputFilter(
                       new \YourModule\Form\YourFilter($options)
                    );
                return $form;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Such solution allows to update zfcuser without overriding your changes.